# How to insert data on Grails 3 through REST API?

Tags: rest, grails

I've build a demo project on Grails 3.0.10

I can read the data with a REST request but I don't know how to insert data.

Here's how my project is built:

```
grails create-app bookstore
cd bookstore
grails create-domain-class bookstore.Book
```

edit file grails-app/domain/bookstore/Book.groovy :

```
package bookstore

class Book {

    String title
    String author
    Date publicationDate

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Scaffold:

```
grails generate-all bookstore.Book
```

Run the app:

```
grails run-app
```

Browse:
    http://localhost:8080

From here I can insert and list items from the browser ;o)

**Now I want to use the REST API !**

Reading data is OK:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -i http://localhost:8080

/book.jsonHTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Application-Context: application:development
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2015 12:14:01 GMT
[{"class":"bookstore.Book","id":1,"author":"James","publicationDate":"2015-12-13T23:00:00Z","title":"Hello"}]
```

But when I try to insert data:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"title":"Test", "author":"Franck"}'

http://localhost:8080/book/create.jsonHTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Application-Context: application:development
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2015 12:16:03 GMT
{"class":"bookstore.Book","id":null,"author":null,"publicationDate":null,"title":null}
```

And nothing is inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `create` action doesn't save anything.  It is used to populate the initial form when creating an instance using a browser form.  You probably want to be invoking the `save` action instead.

This isn't really related to your question but FYI... if you are building a REST interface, you should look at `RestfulController` and/or the `@Resource` annotation.

Comment: I just created a sample project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/bookstore.  See the README there.